# Issue with converting Word document to Excel using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a Word document to an Excel file using Python and Pandas. The Word document contains numbered bullet points and sub-bullet points. I'm able to extract the acceptance criteria from the document and create a Pandas DataFrame, but I'm having trouble. If someone can please help update the code?

Input has Bullets and sub-bullets and formatting
Input:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

1. Sed ac nibh bibendum, malesuada odio at, luctus tellus.

   a. Integer vel dolor sit amet arcu luctus hendrerit in ut sapien.
2. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

   a. Aliquam posuere nulla et ipsum pulvinar malesuada.

   b. Proin rutrum augue quis sollicitudin varius.

   c. Fusce vitae augue hendrerit, tincidunt ex eu, malesuada orci.
3. Suspendisse non sem in ex hendrerit pellentesque.

Expected Output
1 column with 3 rows

[image]

| Sed ac nibh bibendum, malesuada odio at, luctus tellus. a. Integer vel dolor sit amet arcu luctus hendrerit in ut sapien." |
| --- |
| "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. a. Aliquam posuere nulla et ipsum pulvinar malesuada. b. Proin rutrum augue quis sollicitudin varius. c. Fusce vitae augue hendrerit, tincidunt ex eu, malesuada orci. |
| Suspendisse non sem in ex hendrerit pellentesque. |

The code I am using is

```
    from docx2python import docx2python
from openpyxl import Workbook

# Extract text from docx file
doc_result = docx2python('input.docx')
text = doc_result.text

# Split text into lines
lines = text.split('\n')

# Create a new workbook and select the active worksheet
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# Set the title for the first column
ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 'Acceptance Criteria'

# Initialize row counter and cell text
row_counter = 2
cell_text = ''

# Iterate over lines and extract text between capital numerical bullets
for line in lines:
    if line.strip():
        if line[0].isdigit():
            if cell_text:
                ws.cell(row=row_counter, column=1).value = cell_text.strip()
                row_counter += 1
                cell_text = ''
            cell_text += line + '\n'
        else:
            cell_text += line + '\n'

if cell_text:
    ws.cell(row=row_counter, column=1).value = cell_text.strip()

# Save the workbook
wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

Comment: Why use `pandas` for this? Just use `openpyxl` directly.

Comment: Here's the link to the [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module.

Comment: almost there the output excel file has 1) Sed ac nibh bibendum, malesuada odio at, luctus tellus. 
can you remove the 1) from the output?